# Finding value of $p$ which satisfies Binomial probability? Time/space considerations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, computational-complexity, binomial-distribution

I wish to find the value of $p$ between 0 and 1 which satisfies:

$$P[\operatorname{Bin}(n-1, p) < k] = \frac k n$$

Here $k$ and $n$ are integers with $k < n$.

Also, how many computations in terms of $n$ and $k$ would it take for me to reach the solution?

Comment: This is an algebraic equation in $p$ of degree $n-1$; for $n\gt5$ you can't solve it in closed form.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to find the answer numerically?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "finding" an irrational number?